# How to add a Scintilla component to a Qt Creator C++ project?

Tags: c++, qt, scintilla

I would like to use [scintilla](https://www.scintilla.org/) on a Qt project, but I don't know how to start, do I have to include the source files? or is there some library that I can reference?

The only installation examples I have found are for PyQt but I'm using c++ on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

QScintilla is a library derived from Scintilla to use with Qt. This library can be downloaded from https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/download.

To use this library you need to build and install first. As you use Linux, the building process is

```
cd Qt4Qt5
qmake
make
make install
```

Note:

1. The directory  Qt4Qt5 is inside the uncompressed QScintilla directory.
2. Make sure Qt binary path is in your Linux PATH variable.

To use QScintilla in your project, in your .pro file just add the following line.

```
CONFIG += qscintilla2
```

The library comes with an example. To build the example use the following commands in your bash.

```
 cd example-Qt4Qt5
 qmake
 make
```